# Maxwell equation correct statements

Tags: maxwell-equations

Do these four statements correctly define the 4 Maxwell's equations or do I need to add or change something in it ?

1)Gauss's law:
The net electric flux passing through any closed surface is $\large \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}$ the total charge enclosed in that area

2)Gauss's law for magnetism:
The net magnetic field passing through a closed surface is zero (total magnetic field going out = total magnetic field going in) because magnetic mono-poles don't exist

3)Faraday's law of induction:
A changing magnetic field w.r.t time produces an electric field

4)Ampere's circuital law:
A changing electric field or current produces a circulating magnetic field assuming $\frac{dD}{dt} = 0$

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that questions of the form *Is this correct* are not good formats for this Q&A site because the answer (Yes|No) is too short to be a valid answer. It would be best if you wrote the question to be about clarifying your understanding than asking if it is correct.

Comment: Hi , I have written these statements by my self after completely understanding them i just want to confirm that i haven't misunderstood something wrongly . I will try to improve my format from next questions thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. These sentences describe the Maxwell equations. Nevertheless you should add the directions of the fields as they play an important role too, eg. at Ampere's circuital law: A changing electric field or current produces a current circulating in the orthogonal plane of the direction of change of field/current.  [or something like that]
You might even look them up (with "meaning") [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations#Conventional_formulation_in_SI_units).

Comment: Thanks thats all I wanted to confirm that my understanding is correct or not